# EC2 instance inbound rule not working

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have an Apache server listening on port 10801 (running on Amazon linux EC2 instance). I have updated the inbound rule for the security group with custom TCP rule to allow all traffic to port 10801. The process is listening on port 10801

```
>> sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :10801
tcp        0      0 :::10801                    :::*                        LISTEN      24534/httpd
```

When i hit the port number from my browser, it simply spins and fails. I see multiple questions like this and almost every one asks to update the security group which i have done already. Still unable to reach the service through port 10801. Everything works if i run the server on port 80. Seems like im missing something here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. double-check the name/ID of the security group you're using with this server.
2. double-check IP you're using to connect to. Try *IP*, not FQDN .
3. post screenshot of the security group.

Answer (score 5):

Its working now, guess there was a long lag for the rules to become effective. From AWS documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules):

> You can add and remove rules at any time. Your changes are automatically applied to the instances associated with the security group after a short period.